# socket not writing to server

Tags: java, sockets

There are question with the same problem but they are not helping me out.

Below is the code I've been working on where the `ServerSocket` not receiving any message from client `Socket`.

**Server**

```
package rescue_server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohammad Faisal
 */
public class RServer {

    private TreeMap<String, PrintWriter> clients;
    private static final int PORT = 6621;

    private class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

        private PrintWriter writer;
        private BufferedReader reader;

        public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("client handler thread started");
            String msg;
            try {
                while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public RServer() {
        clients = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(RServer.PORT);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("waiting....");
                Socket client = server.accept();
                Thread tclient = new Thread(new ClientHandler(client));
                tclient.setDaemon(true);
                tclient.start();
                System.out.println("got a connection.");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RServer().start();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
package rescue_client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohammad Faisal
 */
public class RClient {

    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 6621;
    private final static String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    private class ServerHandler implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("server handler started.");
            String msg;
            try {
                while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public RClient() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(SERVER_IP);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void startServerHandler() {
        Thread tserver = new Thread(new ServerHandler());
        tserver.setDaemon(true);
        tserver.start();
        sendWelcomeMsg();
    }

    private void sendWelcomeMsg() {
        try {
            writer.write(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        writer.flush();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("starting client...");
        try {
            socket = new Socket(RClient.SERVER_IP, RClient.SERVER_PORT);
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            startServerHandler();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RClient().start();
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm not getting the message on `server` from `client`.

Comment: Maybe you are not sending an actual line?  The server is waiting for a line - something more than just some bytes.

Comment: @MartinJames: in the client `sendWelcomeMsg()` I'm writing it to server

Comment: Add a newline (`"\n"`) to the String being sent.

Comment: @Fildor: thanks! it works. Why its not being sent without `new line`?

Comment: `readLine` waits for a `\n` to know that a line is complete and return the result. So, no newline - no complete line - readline waits ... Not a very technical explanation, but basically, that's what happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket comunication, Java client C server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561941/socket-comunication-java-client-c-server)

Comment: @MohammadFaisal 'Why its not being sent without new line' lol - because you did not tell it to send one, (which is what I was hinting at)!

Comment: @Martin I'd also written a program in which the input from the swing text field is sent to the server.  And in that case I do not need to add the new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

So you have to add one of these in your String that is being sent.